# How to use a dialog box to set a folder path rather than manual enter within Excel VBA console

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA so please bare with me.

I'm looking for a way to use the folder dialog box to set a folder file path rather than the set fldr function I currently have on row 3. I've tried using other answers but cant get it to work with my specific code.

(further if anyone can suggest ways that this pastes the next lot of data leaving a gap after the last paste within the loop that would be much appreciated!)

```
Sub Consolidation_FINAL()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("CURRENT MANUAL FILE PATH INPUT")

y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each wbFile In fldr.Files
    
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "csv" Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
        
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(RowOffSet:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(RowOffSet:=1, ColumnOffset:=0).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "-"
        

        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            
            wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For x = 1 To wsLR
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) 'col 1
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2) 'col 2
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 3) 'col 3
              y = y + 1
            
            Next x
            
        
        Next ws
        
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
              
    End If

Next wbFile

End Sub
```

Comment: For File/Folder picking, try `Application.FileDialog` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a function like this which allows you to pass a default path and set the caption of the dialog.

This code could go below the code you have already, or better, in a separate standard module.

```vb
Function GetFolder(Optional OpenAt As String, Optional strCaption = "Select folder") As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = OpenAt
        .Title = strCaption
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        
    End With
    
End Function
```

You could use it at the start of your code like this.

```vb
Sub Consolidation_FINAL()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object
Dim fdlr As Object
Dim strPath As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strPath = GetFolder()

    If strPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No folder selected!", vbInformation, "No folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
```

Comment: Hi @norrie, thanks so much, this works exactly as I need it to! You've saved me a lot of time!!

Comment: There was a typo in the code I posted, I've fixed that.